# Server Error in '/Source Code' Application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

This is what i get when i try to run my project every time...

think anyone can help?[image]

```
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>    
    <!--
        The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>
    -->
```

Comment: guys please help me... else don't down vote me... the least you can do...

Comment: Do you use multiple web.config files in your website directory or sub-directory? If so, please make sure that we don't set some attributes such as authentication in the sub web.config file.

Comment: might help if we could see a) the whole (or more of) the web.config and b) a bigger screenshot (my poor eyes can't read any of the above) of the error.

Comment: worth mentioning, you were probably down voted for the quality of your question, check here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I'd also like to point out that you won't attract much help by saying, it's "the least you can do".

Comment: seriously, I can't read the image. can you post up the text of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it solved...

just disable the anonymous authentication in IIS, through Administrative tools...

also if you have obsolete database file check that too...